# ros beginner tutorials problem

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, beginner-tutorials, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to execute the command roscd beginner_tutorials or rospack find beginner_tutorials i'm getting a message displaying No such package/stack. plz help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41652/ros-beginner-tutorials-problem/) by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-03-13**:
I also ever met with the same problem! But I always use 'cd' now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you try the followings?

1. Launch a terminal.
2. Open ".bashrc". ".bashrc" is at your home directry(/home/(user-name)/.bashrc).
      eg). **$gedit .bashrc**
3. Check whether there are the following lines or not. If not, add them.
      (
       Assumption:
       1. You use ros electric. If you use other ros versions, change the part "electric".
       2. You made ros_workspace directry at your home directry and created beginner_tutorials package in the directry.
      )
   **export /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash

   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks**

*Second line is important. You need to add the directry which includes packages to environment variable.

If roscd still doesn't work well...

1. Go to beginner_tutorials directry.
      eg). cd ~/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials
2. Type the following command.
      $rosmake
3. Retry "roscd".

---

Originally posted by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) with karma: 721 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the same problem with groovy distribution. I have first wrote:

$source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

and then:

$rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials

the result is:

Error: no such package beginner_tutorials

The solution for my distrubution of ros is the same?

---

Originally posted by [Ziko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4701/ziko/) with karma: 46 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-17**:
Please do not post additional questions as "answers". That is not how this forum works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this : $ source devel/setup.bash
It worked for me. (You should have a catkin workspace already created and your package must be inside the workspace)

---

Originally posted by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) with karma: 225 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-02-10**:
This worked for me, thank you! Just have to make sure you're NOT in the ~/catkin_ws/src directory, but rather in the ~/catkin_ws/ directory :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I just ran into this problem and found it was my own stupidity and not reading CAREFULLY the tutorial instructions.

I have the distro indigo (found by "**echo $ROS_DISTRO**").

So I thought I followed the tutorial and I missed the one step... BEFORE you call:

> **catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp**

Make sure you are in the ~/catkin_ws/src directory.  <- that's the step I missed.

I called catkin_create_pkg from the ~/catkin_ws directory.  WRONG... it's looking for it in the src directory.

Anyway, hope this helps someone else...

---

Originally posted by [netstv](https://answers.ros.org/users/21689/netstv/) with karma: 11 on 2015-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1